# Delete permission on child object of Master Detail relationship

Tags: sharing, master-detail, childrelationship

I need to give delete permission for one object.
That object has Master-detail relationship with Account, and that profile has View all Permission for an Account object.
The profile has Delete and Modify All permission for detail object.
Sharing setting for the field is Ready Only.

The user is still not able to delete child records.
What else permission is needed to delete child record?

Comment: Does changing the sharing setting to "Read/Write" work? I have had so much confusion on this topic [which I had once encountered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294403/what-does-read-write-on-sharing-setting-mean-when-profile-for-object-is-read-onl), still not sure how it works!

Comment: @JayantDas by changing sharing setting to Read/Write, I need to share record with Read/Write permission with user, which I don't want

Comment: I understand, my comment was to just verify if that works.

Answer (score 1):

The create/read/edit on child in MD relation is governed by the setting you choose while creating the relationship.

I am guessing you have selected the second option which is why you are not able to delete child records. To verify you can try the same by giving edit access for one of the master record.

[image]

Comment: Selecting Read/Write on sharing setting means, I need to give Read/Write permission on Account object, in order to Delete child record. In our case I don't want to give. The minimum access they need to have is read to create/edit/delete child record.