# Why am I able to delete a record of the detail object?

Tags: profile, sharing, master-detail, owd

There are two custom objects in a Master Detail Relationship:

1. Employees (Detail object)
2. Projects (Master object)

I built a custom profile that consists of user1, and the object level permissions for both the above objects is set to Read, Create, Edit, Delete only.

View All and Modify All is unchecked for both the objects

In the Sharing Settings(OWD), both the objects are set to public read/write.

Now user1 tries to access the Projects(Master) object and is not able to delete a record created by another user(admin).

Now user1 tries to access the Employees(detail) object and is able to delete a record created by another user(admin).

I don't understand why is this difference coming up?

As per my understanding whatever settings are applied to the Master object will get reflected to the detail object as well, that means if user1 is not able to delete a record of another user in Projects object then the same behaviour must be in Employees object, but it is not happening like that.

Answer (score 1):

Could it have something to do with the edit access for the master record? I found this that seems it might help?  [Delete permission on child object of Master Detail relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343231/delete-permission-on-child-object-of-master-detail-relationship)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Now, this deleting of detailed records is a tricky thing.

I just finished a **Flow** in **System mode** that deletes only the detailed record. Then put it as a Button action on the detailed record.
With the new action filters, you can adjust who sees that button or not.

This is the workaround that I figured out works fine.